# how to do arithmetics with datetimes in CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh, cassandra-3.0

My objective, is to remove a fixed amount of time, from now(). So I always get the last five minutes, or the last five hours.

**How can I achieve it ?**

[The documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/operators.html#id4) on cassandra says:

> A duration can be added (+) or substracted (-) from a timestamp or a
> date to create a new timestamp or date. So for instance:
> `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE t = '2017-01-01' - 2d`
> will select all the records with a value of t which is in the last 2 days of 2016.

inside `cqlsh`, `show version;` gives me:

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.0 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

I test with the following table:

```
cqlsh:> CREATE TABLE t (
    ...   ts        timestamp,
    ...   PRIMARY KEY (ts)
    ... )
    ... WITH compression = {'class': 'LZ4Compressor'}
    ... AND gc_grace_seconds = 60;
```

The following query works:

```
SELECT (float)1.55 FROM t WHERE (ts <= toTimestamp(now()));
```

The followings don't:

```
cqlsh:> SELECT (float)1.55 FROM t WHERE (ts <= toTimestamp(now() - 1d));
SyntaxException: line 1:57 mismatched input '-' expecting ')' (...ts <= toTimestamp(now() [-]...)
cqlsh:> SELECT (float)1.55 FROM t WHERE (ts <= toTimestamp(now()) - 1d);
SyntaxException: line 1:58 mismatched input '-' expecting ')' (... <= toTimestamp(now()) [-]...)
cqlsh:> SELECT (float)1.55 FROM t WHERE (ts <= toTimestamp(now()) - 1m);
SyntaxException: line 1:58 mismatched input '-' expecting ')' (... <= toTimestamp(now()) [-]...)
cqlsh:> SELECT (float)1.55 FROM t WHERE ts <= toTimestamp(now()) - 1m;
SyntaxException: line 1:57 mismatched input '-' expecting EOF (... <= toTimestamp(now()) [-]...)
cqlsh:> SELECT (float)1.55 FROM t WHERE ts = toTimestamp(now()) - 1m;
SyntaxException: line 1:56 mismatched input '-' expecting EOF (... = toTimestamp(now()) [-]...)
```

As you can see the error is always about the `-` when trying to substract the duration. (By the way, the result is the same with `+`)

What do I do wrong? there might be a way to achieve it, but I can't figure it out!

## solution

For the record, as suggested by @Ashraful-Islam my solution has been to create a UDF to do the job. see below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS timeAgo(minutes int) 
  CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
  RETURNS timestamp
  LANGUAGE java AS '
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (minutes == null)
      return new Date(now);
    return new Date(now - (minutes.intValue() * 60 * 1000));
  ';

-- So I can do
SELECT timeAgo(60) FROM t;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Arithmetic Operators introduced in Cassandra 4.0**

> - Add support for arithmetic operators (CASSANDRA-11935)

Source : https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/CHANGES.txt#L124

---

**Edited**

If your cassandra version less than 4.0 then you have to do it from the application layer or create a user define function (UDF). Check the below link

[Creating user-defined function in Cassandra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDF.html)

Comment: Come on! They could at least specify "latest" also means "unstable", as well as which part are stable or not...
Thank you, I update my question to make it more constructive then.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!